# How to return React component inside mapping

Tags: reactjs

I just can't figure out the syntax mistake here, but my React components won't render. What am I doing wrong?

```
return (
  shouldShow && (
    <div>
      {this.props.photos.map(({ url }) => {
        return (
            this.state.expanded
                ? <ImageGallery passedProp={url} />
                : <AnotherComponent passedProp={url}
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
);
```

I get the error:

> JSX attributes must only be assigned a non-empty expression

**EDIT updated full code as requested:**

```
  showGallery = () => {
    const shouldShow = this.props.photos.length > 0;

    return (
      shouldShow && (
        <div>
          {this.props.photos.map(({ url }) => {
            return (
              this.state.expandedThumbnail
                ? <ImageGallery imageUrl={urlurlurl}/>
                : <button
                    key={url}
                    onClick={this.doThis}
                  >
                  <img
                    src={url}
                  />
                </button>
            )
          })}
        </div>
      )
    );
  };
```

Comment: Your component is not closed `<ImageGallery passedProp={url} />`

Comment: @kinduser sorry my component is actually closed. I pared down the example code given above from what I truly have. The component is closed

Comment: It appears that the problem is not caused by posted code, provide the rest of components.

Comment: @kinduser updated

Comment: Show also `ImageGallery`

Comment: where is `doThis` defined?